# RDS does not support creating a DB instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I am trying to create postgres rds using cloudformation but it give me this error

> RDS does not support creating a DB instance with the following combination: DBInstanceClass=db.t2.micro, Engine=postgres, EngineVersion=13.3, LicenseModel=postgresql-license. For supported combinations of instance class and database engine version, see the documentation. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: cdb3ewcd-17ef-404c-adc5-fcd04a590553; Proxy: null).

I have tried changing the instance type and EngineVersion but same error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 myDBEC2SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Frontend Access
      VpcId: !Ref Ec2Vpc
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 5432
        ToPort: 5432
        CidrIp: 10.0.0.0/16
  myDBParamGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBParameterGroup
    Properties:
      Description: Database Parameter Group + pg_stat_statements
      Family: postgres13
      Parameters:
        shared_preload_libraries: pg_stat_statements
  myDBSubnetGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup
    Properties:
      DBSubnetGroupDescription: DB Private Subnet
      SubnetIds:
      - !Ref Ec2SubnetPrivate1
      - !Ref Ec2SubnetPrivate2
  pgDB:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBName: !Ref 'DBName'
      AllocatedStorage: !Ref DBAllocatedStorage
      DBInstanceClass: !Ref 'DBInstanceClass'
      Engine: postgres
      EngineVersion: '13.3'
      MasterUsername: !Ref 'DBUser'
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref 'DBPassword'
      MultiAZ: !Ref 'MultiAZ'
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: Master Database
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref myDBSubnetGroup
      DBParameterGroupName: !Ref myDBParamGroup
      VPCSecurityGroups:
      - Fn::GetAtt:
        - myDBEC2SecurityGroup
        - GroupId
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to find the instance that supports your engine `postgres` and version `13.3` for your region. To do this you should use the [following command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html#Concepts.DBInstanceClass.RegionSupport):

```
aws rds describe-orderable-db-instance-options --engine postgres --engine-version 13.3     --query "*[].{DBInstanceClass:DBInstanceClass,StorageType:StorageType}|[?StorageType=='gp2']|[].{DBInstanceClass:DBInstanceClass}"  --output text
```

which gives (t2 is not supported at all):

```
db.m5.12xlarge
db.m5.16xlarge
db.m5.24xlarge
db.m5.2xlarge
db.m5.4xlarge
db.m5.8xlarge
db.m5.large
db.m5.xlarge
db.m6g.12xlarge
db.m6g.16xlarge
db.m6g.2xlarge
db.m6g.4xlarge
db.m6g.8xlarge
db.m6g.large
db.m6g.xlarge
db.r5.12xlarge
db.r5.16xlarge
db.r5.24xlarge
db.r5.2xlarge
db.r5.4xlarge
db.r5.8xlarge
db.r5b.12xlarge
db.r5b.16xlarge
db.r5b.24xlarge
db.r5b.2xlarge
db.r5b.4xlarge
db.r5b.8xlarge
db.r5b.large
db.r5b.xlarge
db.r5.large
db.r5.xlarge
db.r6g.12xlarge
db.r6g.16xlarge
db.r6g.2xlarge
db.r6g.4xlarge
db.r6g.8xlarge
db.r6g.large
db.r6g.xlarge
db.t3.2xlarge
db.t3.large
db.t3.medium
db.t3.micro
db.t3.small
db.t3.xlarge
db.t4g.2xlarge
db.t4g.large
db.t4g.medium
db.t4g.micro
db.t4g.small
db.t4g.xlarge
db.x2g.12xlarge
db.x2g.16xlarge
db.x2g.2xlarge
db.x2g.4xlarge
db.x2g.8xlarge
db.x2g.large
db.x2g.xlarge
```

Comment: I even got this error when upgrading to 15.2 *and* using a supported version (db.t3.micro), strangely. The work-around to get it working was to **first** change the Class to db.t3.micro by itself, and then upgrade to 15.2.